# Selecting And Displaying Data with the same category from mysql database to my Webpage by click of a button

Tags: php, mysql

php code to get table id`

`include_once('dbconfig/dbcon.php');`

```
 $upload_dir = 'images/';

if(isset($_GET['brand_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['brand_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * from btype where brand_id=".$id;
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg']= 'Could not select record';
    }
}

`
```

display data in webpage`

```
<img src=" echo $upload_dir.$row['bom_pic']; " width= "100" height="100%">
 echo $row['bspects'];


<small>Email : </small><a href = "mailto:<?php echo $row['bemail'];?>"><?php echo $row['bemail'];?></a></h5>`
```

button to retrieve data and display

```
<a href = "listed.php?brand_id='.$row["brand_id"].' ">.$row["bname"].'</a>
```

`
the problem is instead of listing all bname inthe same category it is only displaying one bname

Comment: Okay? And is there something not working or...? What's your question?

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: the problem is it is selecting only one business instead of all business with the same category